# MultiMap vs MultiValue Map

Tags: java, performance, dictionary

At one place i have to use a map with many values mapped to a single key, so i was wondering whether there is any significant performance distinction between using **HashMap of key, list** and **MultiMap of key , values** in java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try it but I doubt there is much difference as it does much the same thing.

IMHO The advantage is simpler/clearer code which is usually more important than performance.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to use google collections if you want to use a more convenient implementation of a Multimap. In case you don't want to introduce a new dependency, `HashMap<Key, Collection<Value>>` should do the trick which is pretty much what apache.collections HashMultiMap does.

Comment: Yes. Google collection is named "Guava". There are some different value collections: HashMultiMap, ArrayListMultiMap...

Answer (score 0):

Hash provides O(1) which is fast and does nothing with the size of elements.

Regarding to Multimap, you could put values in dependent collection (List, Set). Different collection implementations provides different performance.

EDIT: As I commented on Sebastian's answer. You could use Guava which provides different value collection implemantions: `HashMultiMap (HashMap<KEY, HashSet<VALUE>>)`, `ArrayListMultiMap (HashMap<KEY, ArrayList<VALUE>>)`...

Comment: Hashmap/HashTable/Hash* does not provide O(1), in the worst case, where had collisions with all the input keys, it is O(N).

Comment: @Pih: hmm...big O doesn't indicate worst case.

Comment: Ok, I considered the O() notation as the Big O notation, that it is usually used for the worst case. Anyway, Hashtables provides *amortized* O(1) access.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Map Key-> Values, use a Map implementation.

As you will have some Values with the same Keys, use the http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html from the Google Collection (now guava library, http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/ ) for your task.