# duplicate key value pairs

Tags: java, data-structures

Is there a native data structure in java that accepts key value pairs and allows duplicates? I am creating a checklist of characters in a string but some characters occur more than once.

ex

```
j -> false
a -> false
v -> false
a -> false
```

Comment: Not sure about key/value pairs, but have you looked at `Bag`s?  They allow duplicates, and there might be some thing usable there.

Comment: Lots of answers suggest multimap from Guava but I wanted to use standard Java libraries

Comment: `List` + `Pair`, that's what i say ;)

Comment: If you want standard Java, you will have to do a bit of extra work in simulating the "multimap' behavior, as suggested in the answers to your question.

Comment: [This answer in the possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6352551/1711796) suggests standard Java classes.

Comment: Here's another possible duplicate - [HashMap with multiple values under the same key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4956844)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simulate multiple key-value (KV) pairs by saving a list of values for each in a map. This is a standard implementation approach for "multivalue" maps.

So, if the key is a `Character` object and the value is `Boolean`, you can do

```
Map<Character, List<Boolean>> multimap = new HashMap<Character, List<Boolean>>();
```

and every time you want to add a new value to an existing KV pair in the map just call

```
multimap.get(key).add(value);
```

where `key` is the Character and `value` its corresponding `Boolean` value.

The `Guava` library by `Google` (free download) has a [Multimap interface](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implemented in various ways, so essentially you can instantiate a `MultiMap<Character, Boolean>` map and use it accordingly. Similarly, you can get the `Apache Commons Collections` library and use its `MultiValueMap` class. You may also want to check the answers to a [similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830575/multimap-vs-multivalue-map), or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062960/map-implementation-with-duplicate-keys).

If you only want to store one of each value per key, then a `Set` should be used in the place of the `List`.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly you suggesting something that looks like this.
`J, [F] | A [F,F] | V [F]`

Comment: Yes and that is how it would probably be implemented anyway.

Comment: I feel that your solution has better performance then Bobbel's when it comes to lookups but his seems like it would be easier to code

Comment: The approach I suggested is standard practice and you can easily create your own MultiMap class based on it, depending on which functions of the Map interface you want to use. It maintains the KV "map" behavior and does not replicate the key.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `List` of `Pair`s:

```
public class Pair<T, U> {
    public final T key;
    public final U value;

    public Pair(T key, U value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class YourApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair<Character, Boolean>> charList = new ArrayList<Pair<Character, Boolean>>();
        charList.add(new Pair('j', false));
        charList.add(new Pair('a', false));
        charList.add(new Pair('v', false));
        charList.add(new Pair('a', false));

        for (Pair<Character, Boolean> pair : charList) {
            System.out.println(pair.key + " -> " + pair.value);
        }
    }
}
```

With the selfwritten generic `Pair` class you can hold a key and a value of any type you want. If you're adding pairs to a `List`, you can even hold duplicates of pair entries.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MultiMap<Character,Boolean>` bcoz it allows duplicate key which exist in `org.apache.commons.collections` package.

or

You can use `ArrayList` and add the objects of the `Class` that contain attribute as char & boolean pair.

Comment: Just to mention: this is **Apache Commons**, not standard Java.

Comment: yes i know.Who say that this class is in java ??

Comment: Other way round: you **didn't** say that this isn't a standard Java class ;)

Comment: this is well knw class in java external library.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a build in solution.

A quick alternative would be to use a simple ArrayList, and create an object that is a char/boolean pair that you can add to it.

Answer (score 1):

commons.apache.org have MultiHashMap class. Try this one...!!!

```
MultiHashMap mp = new MultiHashMap();
mp.put("a", "1");
mp.put("b", "4");
mp.put("c", "2");
mp.put("a", "6");
List list = null;
Set set = mp.entrySet();
Iterator i = set.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, List<String>> me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
        for(int j = 0 ; j< me.getValue().size(); j++ ){
        System.out.println(me.getKey() +" : " +me.getValue().get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been deprecated. MultiValueMap is the class to use, if going with Apache commons Collections.